# Native Linking Failed,undefined Objective C Class in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nuget, braintree

So i'm trying to use Braintree for a Xamarin Forms Project,for that i've built two seperate nuget packages ,each for iOS and Android,but for some reason when i try to consume it,i get this error in Xamarin Forms

> /#Path#/DemoApp1/DemoApp1.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: BTUIKLocalizedString. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTUIKLocalizedString' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211) (DemoApp1.iOS)

I've gone through the related articles,but it seems the scope of this error is big and there's no definitive way to fix it,i just want to what methodology causes this and I'm not sure how to solve this,any inputs would help

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/NAXAM/braintree-ios-binding) binding? `Naxam.BraintreeUI.iOS` works properly on my side.

Comment: Nope,i' ve created a new binding to avoid issues with my client,as he doesn't want any other party to be involved in it

Comment: Then this issue may be particular.

Comment: I know that's why i'm kinda stuck as to what this might be